# How to change the input tensor shape as picture and description

Tags: python, tf.keras

```
img_rows = 32
img_cols = 32
channels = 3

img_shape = ( img_rows, img_cols, channels) # => discriminator
z_dim = 150 # => generator

def discriminator(img_shape):

    model = Sequential()

    model.add(Conv2D(32, 
                 kernel_size = 3, 
                 strides = 2,
                 input_shape = img_shape,
                 padding = 'same'))

    model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha = 0.01))

    model.add(Conv2D(64, 
                 kernel_size = 3, 
                 strides = 2, 
                 input_shape = img_shape, 
                 padding = 'same'))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha = 0.01))

    model.add(Conv2D(128, 
                 kernel_size = 3, 
                 strides = 2, 
                 input_shape = img_shape, 
                 padding = 'same'))
   model.add(BatchNormalization())
   model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha = 0.01))

   model.add(Flatten())
   model.add(Dense(1,Activation('sigmoid')))

  return model

def gan(generator, discriminator):

   model = Sequential()
   model.add(generator)
   model.add(discriminator)

  return model

discriminator = discriminator(img_shape)
discriminator.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer = Adam(), metrics=['accuracy'])

discriminator.trainable = False
generator = generator(z_dim)

gan = gan(generator, discriminator)
gan.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer = Adam())
```

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
7     return model
8
----> 9 discriminator = discriminator(img_shape)
10 discriminator.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer = Adam(), metrics=['accuracy'])
11
...

...

...

ValueError: Layer sequential_1 expects 1 input(s), but it received 3 input tensors. Inputs received: [<tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=32>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=32>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=3>]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DfUB8.png)

Comment: This line doesn't make any sense: `discriminator = discriminator(img_shape)` What are you doing?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.